# Puma gem error on OS X ElCapton

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, puma

Getting following error while installing puma gem:

```
ERROR:  Error installing puma:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling http11_parser.c
compiling io_buffer.c
io_buffer.c:119:21: warning: passing 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') to parameter of type 'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
  return rb_str_new(b->top, b->cur - b->top);
```

Any clue where i should be looking to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
brew install openssl
brew link --force openssl
```

Check out this GitHub issue, it helped me: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/783

Comment: Could you add the snippet of the answer here itself along with the link to the solution. This would help in retaining the answer for future reference without any dependency on other websites.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by maximf, this is what worked for me :

```
brew install openssl
brew link --force openssl
```